# The correct way to find output wiil be?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I having this as

**input**

```
3
Hong Kong
India
Usa
12
130
20
And Expected output is 
Hong Kong
Usa
India
12
20
130
```

But i'm getting the only Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
How to get the full string.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int no=sc.nextInt();
        String[] cname=new String[no];
        int[] pop=new int[no];
        for(int i=0;i<no;i++){
             cname[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<no;i++){
            pop[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Happens after you read the first integer, then you read the lines `""`, `"Hong Kong"` and `"India"`, now you ask for an int, but the next token is `USA`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? , could you please clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add values like this and also put value into array:

```
int no = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
----------------------------------------
pop[i] =Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: Yep, this is the correct solution for my problem. Can you tell me how  Integer.parseInt help in taking the input?

Comment: ``nextLine()`` recognize Enter button and ``nextInt()`` recognize Space button. When you use ``nextInt()`` and press Enter button it gets number but ``nextLine()`` method takes the line before you press enter. Also ``nextInt()`` takes number like this: https://imgur.com/d3LzeBl.